# no such element: Unable to locate element: when I use elementToBeClickable method

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have to wait for an element to appear and then click on it. Here is the code I tried and getting the NoSuchElementException.

I have 300 seconds to wait for the element, but it is trying to find the element: 
`tpo.fwOptimizationTestResults()` without waiting for 300 seconds

```
WebElement fwResults = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 300))
        .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(tpo.fwOptimizationTestResults())); 

public WebElement fwOptimizationTestResults() {
    //return driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='table table-condensed table-bordered']"));
    return driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[contains(@class, 'table-condensed')]"));
}
```

Error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//table[contains(@class, 'table-condensed')]"}
  (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.80)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception is not from `elementToBeClickable`, it's from `fwOptimizationTestResults`. You are using `driver.findElement()` which throws the exception and evaluates before the expected condition.

There are two overloads, `elementToBeClickable(WebElement)` and `elementToBeClickable(By)`, you should use the second one

```
WebElement fwResults = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 300)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//table[contains(@class, 'table-condensed')]")));
```

Comment: Perfect, can you explain these two overloads, ElementToBeClickable(IWebElement) andElementToBeClickable(By). In the Page object model, I'm using the same xpath as mentioned by you. What makes the difference.

Comment: @VamshiM There are two `elementToBeClickable()` methods, one receive  `WebElement`, which you used, as a parameter and the second one receive `by` as a parameter and locate the element internally, so the time span is used. You tried to locate the element with `driver.findElement()`, which throws an exception immediately.

Comment: please help me out with changes to be made for the fwOptimizationTestResults to avoid this exception. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @VamshiM You can return `By` instead of `WebElement`, `public By fwOptimizationTestResults() {
    return By.xpath("//table[contains(@class, 'table-condensed')]");
}`

Answer (score 1):

You might want to amend your code to add [`ignoring`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html#ignoring-java.lang.Class-) stanza to the [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) 
 so it won't fail on [NPEs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html):

```
WebElement fwResults = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 5))
        .ignoring(NullPointerException.class)
        .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(tpo.fwOptimizationTestResults()));
```

and in its turn put your WebElement function inside the [try block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html) and instead of throwing an exception - return [`null`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/interesting-facts-about-null-in-java/) in case if element is not found:

```
public WebElement fwOptimizationTestResults() {
    try {
        return driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[contains(@class, 'table-condensed')]"));
    } catch (NoSuchElementException ex) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

More information:

- [FluentWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html)
- [How to use Selenium to test web applications using AJAX technology](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/ajax_technology_selenium/)